# Error A2001 in assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

Proc Code:

```
Values PROC ,
```

Text:PTR BYTE, listPtr:PTR BYTE

```
mov edx,Text

L1: call WriteString 

call ReadFloat

      fild 100

      fcomp comVal

      jg endLoop

      fild 100

      fcomp comVal

      jl endPRoc

    fstp REAL8 PTR [esi]

      add esi, TYPE REAL8


endProc:
```

Values ENDP

I invoke it using `invoke storeValues, ADDR prompt, ADDR List` and get the error 2001 and am confused on how to fix it

Comment: There may be another problem: the comma after `PROC` in your first line. `PROC` and arguments are not delimited by a comma, but by a space.

Answer (score 1):

As defined in the [Intel Software Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) page 830, FILD takes a memory operand, not an immediate:

> ```
> DF /0 FILD m16int Valid Valid Push m16int onto the FPU register stack.
> DB /0 FILD m32int Valid Valid Push m32int onto the FPU register stack.
> DF /5 FILD m64int Valid Valid Push m64int onto the FPU register stack.
> ```

You want to define the constants in a data segment, and point to it.
Something like:

```
.data 
hundred dd 100

; ....

.code
fild dword ptr [hundred]
```

Comment: You got a size mismatch. `dw` matches _word ptr_ and `dd` matches _dword ptr_.

Comment: @Fifoernik, thanks for spotting. just edited the answer accordingly.